# Mongodb Index Creation only if not already exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a command that i can use via javascript in mongo shell that can be used to check if the particular index exists in my mongodb. I am building a script file that would create indexes. I would like that if I run this file multiple number of times then the indexes that already exists are not recreated.
I am thinking of using this, will it work:

```
if(db.collection.getIndexes().find({'name':'index_name'}).count()==0) { 
    db.collection.createIndex( { abc: 1, def: 1 } , { name: "index_name" } ) 
}
```

or, there is any better way to do this ?
Also if above code is wrong, please help me with this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a benefit to checking first, unless you plan to cache that response.

When you call `db.collection.createIndex`, it will not re-create an index that already exists, it will return `ok:1` with `"note" : "all indexes already exist"`.

This will take the same database lock as calling `db.collection.getIndexes` or the `listIndexes` database command.  There isn't much difference in checking to see if the index exists first, or just attempting to create it.

Comment: Then please give me a solution for this task to be done.

Comment: Just run `db.collection.createIndex` and let the database determine whether to create it or not.

Comment: Does the above answer apply also to TTL indexes? What happens if the application calls CreateIndex for an already available TTL index, but sets a different ExpirationTime?

Comment: If the index already exists but has options different than the request, whether expiry or other option,  it will return `ok:0` with the message "already exists with different options"